# marrangeGrob giving error for nrow

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra, r-grid

I'm trying to create a bunch of ggplot2 plots using a for loop and then saving them on a multi-page pdf document, and I'm having trouble with marrangeGrob. Here's some example code:

```
 Plots <- list()
 Plots[[1]] <- qplot(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$wt)
 Plots[[2]] <- qplot(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$wt)
 Plots[[3]] <- qplot(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$qsec)
 Plots[[4]] <- qplot(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$drat)

 # install.packages("gridExtra", dependencies = TRUE)
 library(gridExtra)

 MyPlots <- do.call(marrangeGrob, c(Plots, nrow = 1, ncol = 2))
 ggsave("My plots on multiple pages.pdf", MyPlots)
```

I've used similar versions of the `do.call(marrangeGrob...` line in the past and had them work, but now, I get this error when I try to execute that line: `Error: nrow * ncol >= n is not TRUE`. The fact that code similar to this used to work makes me think that something in one of these packages has since been updated. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: `ggsave("out.pdf", marrangeGrob(Plots, nrow = 1, ncol = 2))` perhaps due to recent changes

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I get an error that the `plot should be a ggplot2 plot`.

Comment: ok... couple of options; `pdf("out.pdf"); marrangeGrob(Plots, nrow = 1, ncol = 2) ; dev.off()` or upgrade `ggplot2`, which has now removed the check on ggplot2 objects, or use ahack learned from SO.. `ggsave <- ggplot2::ggsave; body(ggsave) <- body(ggplot2::ggsave)[-2]`, if not upgrading

Comment: ggplot2 is already up to date, but `pdf("out.pdf"; marrangeGrob...` etc. worked great! Thanks!

Comment: ah ok...re the ggplot2 , i think i may have the dev version from [github](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax has changed a little with the new `grobs` argument. You should use

```
marrangeGrob(grobs=Plots, nrow = 1, ncol = 2)
```

or, equivalently,

```
do.call(marrangeGrob, list(grobs=Plots, nrow = 1, ncol = 2))
```

Comment: how can we ensure to save one plot per page using the above commands ?